# sharedpreference return whole list not the one seleected in card

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I have two activities one is "products" and the other is "cart", I used sharedpreferences to save the selected product and display it in the cart activity, the problem is when I press on add to cart the whole list of products is displayed not just the selected product

my products Adapter

```
public class productsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<productsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<products> productList;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, count;
    public ImageView thumbnail, cart;
    private Context context;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {


        super(view);

        context = itemView.getContext();
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        cart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart);


    }
}


public productsAdapter(Context mContext, List<products> productList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.productList = productList;

}

@Override

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.products_card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final products p = productList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(p.getName());
    holder.count.setText(p.getPrice() + "L.E");
    Glide.with(mContext).load(p.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), product_details.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("img", p.getThumbnail());
            bundle.putString("name", p.getName());
            bundle.putInt("price", p.getPrice());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    holder.cart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

    holder.cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            holder.cart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_cart);

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(productList);
            editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

            editor.commit();


        }
    });
}


public int getItemCount() {

    return productList.size();
}


}
```

**my cart activity**

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button l;
ImageView imv;
Toolbar t;
RecyclerView rv;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
List<products> cartitems;
ArrayList<products> selected_items_list = new ArrayList<>();
SharedPreference sharedPreference;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
int countt = 0;
boolean edit_mode = false;
TextView counterr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mycartrecycler);
    layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String jsonFavorites = preferences.getString(FAVORITES, null);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    products[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
            products[].class);

    cartitems = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
    cartitems = new ArrayList<products>(cartitems);
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cartitems, CartActivity.this);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you add the whole list in sharedpreferences.. look at below

you did this...

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(productList);
```

1) if you want the specific selected result then you have to make a pojo class of product with the contain details like

```
public TextView title, count;
public ImageView thumbnail, cart;
private Context context;
```

and make getter and setter method of all fields.

in onclick method of cart,you have to pass that pojo class and get that class in your cart activity. that's how you can get your desire output.

2) the second way to add all details as a field of sharedpreferences like

```
editor.putString("title",title.getText().toString());
```

and set all count and thumbnail as an value.

I hope it will help you...

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want the position of the selected list not just details i tried to put each detail like that but it won't save anything,can you explain more what you mean with pojo class

Comment: I think you made the bean class of product right?... then u have to just get the text of the fields and pass it to sharedpreferences.... like holder.title.getText().toString()... simple ... no need to take the position to populate the list again.....

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `productList` in `SharedPreference`.

Try like this

```
final Product product = productList.get(position);

// Some other code
holder.cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        holder.cart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_cart);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(product);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

        editor.commit();
    }
});
```

In CartActivity

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Product product = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
        Product.class);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,i tried it when i go to the cart activity the app stopped

Comment: @RehamAlatris I've updated the answer please check it

Comment: i did it and then i put in in the list like that
  p = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites, products.class);

        cartitems.add(p);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
but it still stopping :((